# How to Configure SPF or SRV Record on EntryDNS.net?

Tags: spf, srv-records

I'm trying to use EntryDNS.net for my DNS records and the A, CNAME and MX records weren't a problem but I cannot get my SPF (txt) record to work or my SRV records. Does anyone else use them and have you been able to successfully create an SPF or SRV record? Specifically, I'm trying to use these with Office365.

Office365 advises me to use these entries for the SPF record:
Name: @, Content: v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all, TTL: 3600.It worked just fine on my last DNS record host so I don't think the content is the issue. The problem is that the record just doesn't show up for Office365 when I try to verify it nor does it show up when I check it with any webtools sites.

It's the "Name" field that seems to be wonky on EntryDNS.net. For the CNAME, A and MX records, the weird thing on EntryDNS.net was that I had to type the full domain name [autodiscover.domain.com] rather than on my previous site where it assumed the domain name and I would just type in the prefix [autodiscover] in the "name" field. I wondered if this is causing issues with the SPF record?

Comment: Why don't you just contact entrydns.net support?

Comment: They have very limited support and have not responded to my question. I will eventually move away from them if I cannot get this resolved but wanted to see if anyone else was using them for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while for EntryDNS to respond but they eventually did with the correct syntax for the records I was trying to create. The hard part about changing DNS entries, regardless of the host, is that it takes time to propagate so it takes a while before you know if you entered everything correctly or not.

Comment: Can you show or explain the correct syntax so that others can benefit from your answer?